# Simple authentication in EJB 3.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, glassfish, ejb, ejb-3.1

I have an EJB 3.1 application and java clients connecting with this application.
I need to create a user authentication.

Example:

```
class LoginBean{

public remoteLogin(String login, String password){
  // create user context with user ID
}
}

class BeanAbc{
  public remoteSecureMethod(){
      // get user context - if no context throw error
      // get user ID/login from user context and do some additional logic..
  }
}
```

User credentials are stored in DB. I'm using Glassfish server. How to store the user context? What is the best solution? Are there any simply frameworks?

Comment: The simple framework you are looking for is JavaEE itself :-)

Comment: OK, but could you give me example? I have found some JAAS examples but always using web applications. I do not have web application but only java clients connecting directly to ejb server.

Comment: I cannot find any good example on the internet :( Please help

Answer (score 2):

Basically (as far as I know) the client app security in EJB 3.1 is still like the one in 2.x so you should find examples.

What you need to set up:

- jaas login module on the server side (as you have seen for web apps)
- client properties file that determines how to handle authentication
- client side callback, that provides the client-side auth process with the credentials
- start the client with the property file on the class path

This is an example for jboss-as, but I think you can translate that to other servers, as the idea is generic:

```
# file auth.conf on the client 
adb {
   // jBoss LoginModule
   org.jboss.security.ClientLoginModule  required
   ;
};
```

This basically says that for the login context `adb` the client login module needs to succeed. This context `adb` is linked to the respective application jaas context on the server side.

In the code you set up the login like this:

```
CallbackHandler cbh =
    new LoginCallbackHandler(user,pass.toCharArray());
try {
    LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("adb",cbh); 
    lc.login();  // <--- triggers the show in the client
}
catch (LoginException e) {
    System.err.println("Login failed: "+e.getMessage());
}
```

In the LoginContext you give the context `adb` from the auth.conf file above.

The `LoginCallbackHandler` could look like this:

```
package de.bsd.adb.client;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.PasswordCallback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;

public class LoginCallbackHandler implements CallbackHandler {
  private String user;
  private char[] pass;
  // Konstruktor
  LoginCallbackHandler(String username,char[] password) {
    user=username;
    pass=password;
  }
// handle() does the real work and is invoked from the client container
  public void handle(Callback[] callbacks)
    throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException
  {
    // Iterate over the call backs
    for (int i =0 ; i< callbacks.length; i++)
    {
      // NameCallback -> pass Login-Name 
      if (callbacks[i] instanceof NameCallback)
      {
        System.out.println("NameCallback");
        NameCallback nc = (NameCallback)callbacks[i];
        nc.setName(user);
      }
      // PasswordCallback -> pass Password
      else if (callbacks[i] instanceof PasswordCallback)
      {
        System.out.println("PasswordCallback");
        PasswordCallback pc =
            (PasswordCallback)callbacks[i];
       pc.setPassword(pass);
      }
      else {  // unknown callback            
         throw new UnsupportedCallbackException(callbacks[i],"Ouch");
     }}}
```

Now you can start your client program with

```
java -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/auth.conf -cp bla my.Main
```

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely look at **Spring Security**, which is the de-facto standard security framework for Java EE apps. Even if you only use a tiny part of the framework at the beginning, it will put you on the right track and allow you to evolve as you need (if you want to switch authentication method, manage authorization, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add on the answer provided by @Heiko Rupp -
The code he provided will work well as standalone application.
If you're using an application server, you should check how to configure the JAAS modules using the application server configuration. 
For example, at [oVirt](http://www.ovirt.org) open source project we're using a Kerberos Login Module. 
We're currently using JBoss AS 7. 
We have configured the standalone.xml configuration file by defining a security-domain under the security-domains section -

```
 <security-domain name="EngineKerberosAuth">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule" flag="required"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```